# why net.blobs['fc7'].data[0] giving all zeros

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to extract face descriptors from photos of people. This is what I've done so far:

1. First detected faces from photos using opencv library in python.
2. Saved those faces in another image.
3. Next I have to extract descriptor from face image.

For this I have downloaded `vgg face caffemodel` CNN from here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/

To extract descriptor, first I did this:

```
 net = caffe.Net('CAFFE_FACE_deploy.prototxt','CAFFE_FACE.caffemodel',caffe.TEST)
 img = caffe.io.load_image( "detectedface.jpg" )
 img = img[:,:,::-1]*255.0 
 avg = np.array([129.1863,104.7624,93.5940])
 img = img - avg 
 img = img.transpose((2,0,1)) 
 img = img[None,:]
 out = net.forward_all( data = img )
```

But it gives dimension mismatch error that data should be of dimension `(50,3,224,224)` instead of `(50,3,490,490)`

Then I tried this:

```
  # input preprocessing: 'data' is the name of the input blob ==  net.inputs[0]
  transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
  transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
  transformer.set_mean('data', np.load(caffe_root + 'python/caffe/imagenet/ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy').mean(1).mean(1)) # mean pixel
  transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)  # the reference model operates on   images in [0,255] range instead of [0,1]
  transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))  # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB

  net.blobs['data'].reshape(50,3,224,224)

  net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', caffe.io.load_image('detectedface.jpg'))
  out = net.forward()

  feats = net.blobs['fc7'].data[0]
```

Here when I `print feats`, it displays all zeros. Why is it so?

Comment: Did you check if any layer has all-zero weights? This happens when your layer names in the prototxt are different from the weights file.

Comment: No because Its a pretrained network and tested. please help.

Comment: for k in net.params.keys(): print(net.params[k][0].data) this will iteratre through the layers and print the weights. If you get a layer with all-zero weights, then something went wrong during loading the pre-trained weights. That something is often a mismatch between the layer names in the network definition and the names used in the prototxt that was used during training.